# I am trying to delete a record from my table but I get an 'incorrect bindings supplied error'

Tags: python, sqlite

Here is my code:

```
def delWorker():
    deleteWorker = input('Please type in the surname of the worker you would like to delete. ')
    c.execute("DELETE FROM employees WHERE lastName = (?)",
              (deleteWorker))
    conn.commit()
```

I am getting error as  `'incorrect bindings supplied error'`

Answer (score 2):

You want

```
c.execute("DELETE FROM employees WHERE lastName = (?)", (deleteWorker,))
```

=> notice the trailing comma after `deleteWorker`, this is what creates a `tuple` - The parens are only there for disambiguation, so without the comma what Python sees is:

```
c.execute("DELETE FROM employees WHERE lastName = (?)", deleteWorker)
```

so you're actually passing a string when `cursor.execute()` expects a `tuple` or `list`.